# What is causing this jasmine test failure?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I'm working with my jasmine test suite, and I'm getting a weird error that causes the test to fail.  The code works, and I've verified by debugging the tests that the values I expect are the values present, but the test fails.  I get this as output:

```
 Failed
at stack (/Users/username/code/source/client/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2200:17)
at buildExpectationResult (/Users/username/code/source/client/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2170:14)
at Spec.expectationResultFactory (/Users/username/code/source/client/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:777:18)
at Spec.addExpectationResult (/Users/username/code/source/client/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:450:34)
at Env.fail (/Users/username/code/source/client/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1192:25)
at next.fail (/Users/username/code/source/client/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4046:19)
```

This is what my tests look like

```
describe('the returned type', () => {
  afterEach(store.clearActions);
  beforeEach(done => {
    mock.onPatch(url).replyOnce(200, { updated_at: moment().toISOString() });
    save(4, value)(store.dispatch, store.getState)
      .then(() => setTimeout(done, 750));
  });
  it('should have correct type', () => {
    const action = store.getActions()[0];
    expect(action.type).toEqual(LAST_SAVED_UPDATE);
  });
});
```

Comment: You sure that is a synchronous test?

Comment: I imagine `store.clearActions` is a function; you're not calling it.

Comment: @RichChurcher nono, this is just a way of specifying the `beforeEach` function..normally it is `beforeEach(function () { ... });`.

Comment: Isn't the debugger going to stop execution?

Comment: @alecxe Too true, teach me for not reading it properly!

Comment: Sorry, that debugger shouldn't have been there; I removed it from the question.